# WSO2 BPEL import wsdl services with different namespaces but using same schema namespace

Tags: namespaces, wsdl, wso2, bpel

I am using WSO2 BPS 3.2.0, WSO2 Application server 5.2.1 and WSO2 Identity server 5.0.0.
My process invokes many services so it imports many WSDLs.
BPEL's WSDL has this:

```
<import location="Service1.wsdl" namespace="http://webservice1.com/"/>  
<import location="Service2.wsdl" namespace="http://webservice2.com/"/>
```

But two web services imports schemas in same namespace.
So Service1.wsdl has

```
<wsdl:types>
  <xsd:schema>
    <xsd:import namespace="http://Message.com" schemaLocation="webservice1.xsd"></xsd:import>
  </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

and Service2.wsdl has

```
<wsdl:types>
  <xsd:schema>
    <xsd:import namespace="http://Message.com" schemaLocation="webservice2.xsd"></xsd:import>
  </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

WSDLs are valid and everything look OK until I try to deploy process.
Then I get exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.ode.bpel.compiler.api.CompilationException: error: [CompilationErrors] Compilation completed with 4 error(s):
file:/D:/WSO2/WSO2BP~1.0/bin/../tmp/work/bpelTemp/1.4320261653222122E12/messageProcess_1.0.0/messageProcess.bpel:52: error: [UndeclaredXsdType]
Attempt to reference undeclared XSD type "{http://Message.com}Message".
file:/D:/WSO2/WSO2BP~1.0/bin/../tmp/work/bpelTemp/1.4320261653222122E12/messageProcess_1.0.0/messageProcess.bpel:176: error: [UndeclaredVariable]
Attempt to reference undeclared variable "Service1PLRequest".
null:190: error: [UndeclaredVariable] Attempt to reference undeclared variable "Service1PLRequest".
```

The only way I found to avoid this is rename schema namespace for one of service WSDL (remove one of webservice works too :) ).
But both services uses same 3rd party schema and namespace rename is not appropriate. How to solve this puzzle? Is there some best practice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Eduard Nickel.

Sorry, I didnt get it..

You said that both web services share the same namespace...but you presented different namespaces.

```
import location="Service1.wsdl" namespace="http://webservice1.com/
import location="Service2.wsdl" namespace="http://webservice2.com/
```

Other problem seems to be related to wrong variable name.

Service1PLRequest dont exists...

Comment: Hi. Sorry I was not clear enough. 
Each servise (Service1, Service2) have own namespace and its are different. But both services use partly same schema with same namespace. For example: we may have service Customers with namespace _http://stack.com/customers_ and service Organizations with namespace _http://stack.com/organizations_. Both of them use schema address.xsd with namespace _http://info.com/address_. 
Service1PLRequest really exist but is unrecognized because of problem with namespace (I think). Problem was solved by reorganize namespaces in one of services.